# NSIS CopyFiles with UNC path

Tags: nsis

I'm having an issue with a simple FileCopy operation in NSIS where it fails if the source is a UNC path

```
${FileCopy} "$UNCformsubmit\*.*" "D:\UNC\$uncsubfolder"
```

I have tried verifying if i can read files on both the source/destination folder using FileExists, both are accessible. This also confirms that both the path's exist

I've also tried swapping out the double quotes for single quotes or removing them all together.

If $UNCformsubmit is set to a local folder or even a mapped drive, i get no errors.

Is there something special i should be doing in regards to copying from a UNC path? I cannot seem to find anything in the documentation

Comment: How do you specify the UNC path value to ```$UNCformsubmit```? (UNC paths starts with double backslashes ```\\```)

Answer (score 0):

`CopyFiles` is just a thin wrapper on top of [`SHFileOperation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shfileoperationa) and I just tested and UNC paths work just fine:

```
CopyFiles "\\Machine\Share\*.*" "$Temp"
```

Make sure that whatever is in `$UNCformsubmit` is a proper UNC path...